# How to count the number of letters and row a text in tkinter text widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to count the number of letters and row a text in tkinter text widget.
This is my sample code:

```
from tkinter import *

def letter_refresh():
    pass   

def row_refresh():
    pass

app=Tk()

label=Label(text='writing')
label.grid(row=1, column=0)

text = Text( )
text.insert(1.0,"abcd\nefgh\n\nijkl\nmnop")
text.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5, pady=20)


letter=Button(text='letter_count', command = letter_refresh)
letter.grid(row=2, column=0,padx=1, pady=1)

letter_display=Entry()
letter_display.grid(row=2, column=1,  padx=5, pady=5,sticky=W)



row=Button(text='row_count', command = row_refresh)
row.grid(row=3, column=0,padx=1, pady=1)

row_display=Entry()
row_display.grid(row=3, column=1,  padx=5, pady=5,sticky=W)

app.mainloop()
```

I want to `letter_count` result is 16, if `letter_count` botton push.

I want to `row_count` result is 4, if `row_count` botton push.

Answer (score 1):

An entry's text is nothing more than a string.

To count the rows you can split on `\n` and check the `len` of the returned list.

To count the letters simply check the `len` of the string. You will probably want to subtract the number of `'\n'` from that value (`len(string) - string.count('\n')`).

Comment: The wording of this answer isn't quite right. The question is about a `Text` widget, not an `Entry` widget.  That first sentence should be "A Text widget's text is nothing more than a string)

Comment: @DeepSpace, this might be so late but i am trying to figure out how can  i do the same with columns?

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
`Text` widget has `insert` and `get` methods, so it's only matter of using them.

```
txt = Text(root)
txt.pack()

def count(t):
    text = t.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
    rows = text.count('\n')
    letters = len(text) - rows
    return letters, rows

# in your case
print('Letters: {}\n Rows: {}'.format(*count(txt)))
```

Comment: If a row has space(or more than one word) this will not work. You should explicitly split using `\n` and check for empty new lines. Also seems like letters and rows got mixed in your code.

Comment: This question is about a `Text` widget, not an `Entry` widget. You can't insert newlines in an `Entry` widget, and the `get` method of a `Text` widget requires arguments.

Comment: Heh, really. Corrected it. `str.count('\n')` works better than `len(str.split('\n'))`