# How to create a letter counter with Tkinker?

Tags: python, tkinter

I just started to learn Python and I'm trying to create a mineral counter by only using letters for microscopic petrography, but I am having problems passing my python code to Tkinker. Can you guys give tips about how to get my output to work? I'm finding it challenging to use the`get()` method even with online tutorials.

Can you guys teach this noob? Thank you!

My original code:

```py
# define sample
sample = "qreqqwer"

# mineral q:
mineralq= "q"

countq = sample.count(mineralq)

# print count of q
print("The quantity of q is: ", countq)
```

The structure I made with Tkinker:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

# Window
window=tk.Tk()
window.title("Mineral Counter")
window.geometry("800x1000")
window.configure(bg="#00090F")

inputUser=tk.Text(window,width=225,height=5,font=("Arial bold",12),wrap="word", bg="#00090F", fg="white")
inputUser.pack()

# define sample

# mineral q:


countq = inputUser.count("q")

# print count of q
output.insert(tk.INSERT,countq)
output=tk.Text(window,width=20,height=2,font=("Arial bold",12), bg="#00090F", fg="white")
output.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have to use a button to update the gui once the `Text` is filled, i could add an anwer, but is it necessary to use `Text`, could it be an `Entry` widget instead? will your text be that long?

Comment: Ive added an updated answer that does not use `messagebox` and might be what you want, do let me know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the number of letters and row a text in tkinter text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865977/how-to-count-the-number-of-letters-and-row-a-text-in-tkinter-text-widget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a button to update your code, becuase initially the `Text` boxes are empty and hence there is no occurence for `q` so nothing can be inserted.

Try this out:

First create a button with a function to click onto after the data is entered

```
b = tk.Button(window, text='Click Me', command=click)
b.pack()
```

Then now define the function that the button calls when is clicked onto

```
def click():
    sample = inputUser.get('1.0', 'end-1c') #getting value from text box 1
    mineralq = 'q' #letter to be counted
    countq = sample.count(mineralq) #counting the letter
    output.insert('1.0', f'The quantity of q is: {countq}') #inserting the output to text box 2
```

Hope it cleared your doubt, if any errors do let me know

Cheers